# Reading arrays pixel by pixel, getting UnpicklingError

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pickle

I have previously saved thousands of 2D numpy arrays (600x600) to a binary file with `pickle`. I saved them one by one due to memory constraints, and now I'd like to read them in one by one, perform some operations and save the new arrays (also one by one) to a new file. Then my last goal is to read in these new arrays one by one, and append the pixel value to a new list corresponding to a given position. But for some reason I'm getting an `UnpickingError`, and I'm not sure why.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle

def normalize(data_set):
    data_set *= 1/data_set.max()
    with open('final_images.data', 'a+b') as f:
        pickle.dump(data_set, f)
    return data_set

with open('initial_data.data', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            data_set = pickle.load(f)
            # other operations
            final_img = normalize(data_set)
        except EOFError:
            break

filename = 'final_images.data'
def sort_by_pixel(i, j):
    pixels_at_position = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                array = pickle.load(f) #GET ERROR HERE
                fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(600,600))
                fp[:] = array[:]
                pixels_at_position.append(fp[i][j])
            except EOFError:
                break
    return pixels_at_position

stacked = []
for i in range(600):
    for j in range(600):
        stacked.append(np.median(sort_by_pixel(i, j)))
```

The error that I get at the line I indicated is:

`pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you `np.memmap(filename, …)`, that's the same filename you used for the pickle file. So as soon you `fp[:] = array[:]`, you're replacing all of the pickle data with raw array data instead. But then you try to unpickle that raw array data as if it were a pickle, which it isn't (unless you get really unlucky), so it fails.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but the fix might be as simple as having separate `final_images.pkl` and `final_images.bin` files or something. Or maybe it's as simple as not using a `memmap` in the first place, and just appending `array[i][j]` (or, likely better, `array[i, j]`).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but the error occurs before the `memmap` line anyway. And with the `memmap` I'm only trying to generate an array (that won't save in memory)

Comment: But (a) why do you even need that mmap, when you have the exact same array in memory in the first place, and (b) why are you trying to use the same file you're in the middle of reading as the backing store for the mmap?

Comment: Your code is also confusing in other ways. Your `normalize` function saves something to a file and does a `return` with no value, so it just returns `None`, but then you call it with `final_img = normalize(data_set)`. I'm not sure what that's supposed to do, but I suspect it's not the same thing as what it actually does.

Comment: Corrected a typo in the return statement. Initially I was recommended to try to use `mmap` in my previous question, because my arrays are rather large and I do not want to save them all in memory at once. What I need is a more efficient way to accomplish just grabbing a value at pixel position (i, j) for each array (then making a 1D array out of these), but I'm not sure if efficiency here is possible.

Comment: But you're _already_ not saving them into memory all at once. As soon as one loop ends and the next loop starts, you reassign `array` to the next array, so the old one becomes garbage and gets freed. Also, having the array in memory and _also_ having a copy in a file isn't going to be more efficient than just having the array. You're using at least the same amount of real memory, plus twice as much virtual memory, plus disk space and disk I/O time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a perfectly valid pickle file, `final_images.data`, that you've appended pickle dumps to. So, the first time through the loop, `array = pickle.load(f)` will work.

But then you mmap the same file:

```
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(600,600))
```

This `fp` is going to be full of garbage, attempting to interpret a stream of pickles as raw array data, but since you don't actually use that data, it doesn't matter.

But then you overwrite the entire file with the raw array data of the last pickle you loaded:

```
fp[:] = array[:]
```

And now, the file isn't a valid pickle file anymore, it's that raw data.

So, the next time through the loop, when you `pickle.load` from it, it's going to fail, giving you exactly the error you're seeing.<sup>1</sup>.

---

If you actually need a mmap here, you want to store it in a *different* file, not overwrite the pickle file you're in the middle of reading:

```
fp = np.memmap(filename + '.raw', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(600,600))
```

But really, I can't see what good the mmap is doing in the first place. You've already got the exact same array in memory, as `array`. Making a `memmap` and then copying the data to it is just wasting resources for no benefit that I can see. If you just remove that line entirely, and do `pixels_at_position.append(array[i][j])`, it should have exactly the effect you were after.<sup>2</sup>

I'm not actually *sure* that's what you're after, because what your code seems to be trying to do is build a list of the `(i, j)`th values of each array in the pickle, but the name of the function, `sort_by_pixel`, sounds like what you actually want is something completely different from that (something that's sorted, for one thing).

---

<sub>1. Actually, it's only going to fail if you get lucky. If the raw data is small enough. the `f` file pointer could be past the end, and you'd just get an EOF. And if you're *really* unlucky, the raw data could happen to be interpretable as the pickle for a tuple of datetime objects or something crazy, and you'll just silently produce a ton of garbage.</sub>

<sub>2. Except you really should be using `[i, j]`, not `[i][j]`. The latter has to create a row object just so it can index it. That isn't too expensive, since the row is just a slice into the same memory as the original array, but it's still not free. And it's also less idiomatic, and therefore less clear—someone reading `[i, j]` knows you're indexing a 2D array; someone reading `[i][j]` will expect that you're indexing a (possibly jagged) sequence of sequences and have to go figure out that it's actually a 2D array.</sub>